# how to use multiple conditions in one dataframe in r

Tags: r

I am trying to apply these four criteria to one dataframe. Is there a way to use it on just one dataframe rather than creating separate dataframes ?

```
Yellow<- apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x < 45, 'Yellow', ""))
Green <- apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 45 & x < 60, 'Green', "" ))
Orange <- apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 60 & x < 70, 'Orange', "" ))
Red <- apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 45, 'Red', "" ))
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: have a look at `dplyr::case_when`

Comment: your conditions are overlapping. condition red x > 45 overrules orange and green

Comment: so what should be fix

Comment: @gurtej, looking at your conditions, I would say red should be x >= 70.

Answer (score 2):

You can do all the steps in one anonymous function passed to `apply`.

```
apply(df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
  x[x < 45] <- "Yellow"
  x[x > 45 & x < 60] <- "Green"
  x[x > 60 & x < 70] <- "Orange"
  x[x > 70] <- "Red"
  x
})
```

Note that you will miss values for 45, 60 and 70 since `<` and `>` look for values less/greater than x (but not equal). To avoid that, you should use something along the lines of `x <= 45`.

Comment: Thank you very much but its giving me just "red in all the columns

Comment: maybe because the last line must be:
x[x > 70] <- "Red"

Comment: @gurtej see Peter's comment. Note that my code is per your specification, but I should have caught the error. Thanks, Peter!